# Cake PHP 3.5 route

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a controller, `ShareController`, and a method, `view`:

```
class ShareController extends AppController
{

    public  function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
    }

    public function index()
    {


    }

    public function view($id)
    {

        die('here');
    }

}
```

And I have a route:

```
Router::defaultRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);
Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/forsale/:id', ['controller' => 'Share', 'action' => 'view'])
        ->setPatterns(['id' => '\d+'])
        ->setPass(['id']);;

    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});

Router::prefix('sitecontrol', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Admins', 'action' => 'login']);
    $routes->connect('/dashboard', ['controller'=>'Admins','action'=>'dashboard']);
    $routes->connect('/logout', ['controller'=>'Admins','action'=>'logout']);
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the Plugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
Plugin::routes();
```

When I visit `http://thewebsite/forsale/197` I get redirected to: http://thewebsite/users/login?redirect=%2Fforsale%2F197

What could be causing this redirect? I am expecting to see "here".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redirected to login page because of Authentication module. As you have not allowed view action for non logged in user, you need to bypass auth for view action. Please modify beforefilter function as following:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow('view');
}
```